# Como comparar operadores Aritméticos?

Tags: chart.js

Un Saludo.

Sucede que estoy comparando un char con otro en Java, puntualmente un operadores aritmeticos.

Y aunque son iguales por algun motivo el compilador me dice que son diferentes.
ejem.
texto[i] (vale '+')
operador [i] (tambien vale '+')
luego los comparo asi

if(texto[i]!=operador[i]){
muestre error...
}

y.. El output es error

Por que?

Comment: La comparación de chars definitivamente está bnien hecha, deberías de compatir el código completo para poderte ayudar  .

Comment: public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    
      char[] texto = {'+'};
      char[] operador = {'+'};
      
      if(texto[0]!=operador[0]){ 
          System.out.println("diferentes");
      } else{ 
          System.out.println("iguales");
      }
    }
  }